# iOS 8 image editor that allows resizing

Tags: ios, image-editor, iphone-app

I was looking for an app that would allow me to save images to a set resolution or file size. I saw many stand alone apps that did this but installing an app with that limited functionality is just bloat. I'd prefer a general purpose image editor that included this feature but found none. Also preferable is an interface isn't too old (I've come from Android and the iOS 6 and below bubble 'back' button are an eyesore).

Comment: I found [Image Size](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/image-size/id670766542?mt=8), which has has a relatively clean and modern interface. It is a standalone app, though. (See [my related question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/25931/4657).) I haven't seen any full-featured image editors that let you scale to a specific size.