# iOS app to resize / scale images

Tags: ios, image-editor

I'm looking for a simple, well-regarded app that can resize / scale photos I take. There are a few already on the App Store, but they have poor ratings (less than 4 out of 5 stars), or fallen out of date (not updated for the iPhone 6 generation). It can but doesn't need to be a dedicated app; any image editor that allows me to specify pixel dimensions will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After additional digging, I found [Image Size](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/image-size/id670766542?mt=8) by vsmedia.de, which fits the bill for now. As of this writing, it has 4.5 stars and is updated for iPhone 6.